# Java mySQL remote connection through JDBC: ODBC bridge

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, odbc

I am having problems remotely connecting to my mySQL database in Java. Here is my error message:

java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

I am sure my ip address & port I am using work, since I am using the same ip & port for a mySQL client program.

My hosting company do not support JDBC so I am using a JDBC-ODBC bridge.

Here is my class:

```
public class SQLdataBase {

private Connection con;
private Statement st;
private static final String url="jdbc:odbc://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3306";
private static final String className="sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";

    private static  String user;
private static  String pass;

 SQLdataBase(String userName, String password) {
           user=userName;
        pass=password;
    try {
            Class.forName(className);
 con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
 System.out.println("success");
            st = con.createStatement();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
  //do whatever database processing is required
 }

    public void queryNoReturn(String query) throws SQLException{
        st.executeQuery(query);
    }

 }
```

The error occures at this line:
con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should probably contact your hosting company's support

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> String url="jdbc:odbc://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3306";
> ```

In ODBC, you normally use the data source name (DSN) instead of hostname:port in URL. If this is unclear and/or not directly revealable in the documentation of the hosting, then you'll need to contact them for the exact DSN. Once known, then use the following URL:

```
 String url="jdbc:odbc:dataSourceName";
```